# Flash AS3 client-side image crop, rotate, scale and upload

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, image, image-processing, flash-cs5

I am looking to do a client side image crop/scale (creating thumbnails) then upload the cropped image, along with a scaled version of the full sized image (max-size 700x700, for instance)

I also want to be able to offer the chance to rotate the image if needed.

The reasons for this are numerous, mainly to do with the vastly reduced (100-200KB) upload size (compared with 5-7MB for full images).

Also it gives the user more control over what gets uploaded and will provide a reduced upload time if the processing is done in Flash AS3.

I have looked on google for everything I require but I can only find each thing separately and do not have access to the .fla files for the projects to put them all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
You seem to be correct. I must have missed that memo :)

1. Load file from user drive into a bitmap object.
2. Do transformations on bitmap object.
3. Draw the transformed bitmap object onto another bitmap, using the transformed size.
4. Encode to jpg data using JPEGEncoder from AS3 core lib (https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib)
5. Upload the resulting bytes to a server as normal.
6. ???
7. Profit!

If you have any more specific questions about the different parts, it might be better to open new questions.

<strike>I might be wrong, but afaik it's not possible to load an arbitrary image from the users drive into a flash application without first uploading it to a webserver. This is due to safety restrictions.</strike>

It would be done something like this;

1. User selects file to upload.
2. Whole file is uploaded.
3. Whole file is downloaded (or reduced if changes are made to the file on the server) into the flash app again.
4. Changes are made by the user in the flash app.
5. File is uploaded again.

If you can get your users to install an AIR-app, you should be able to do what you want however.

It might also be possible if you use another technology (such as Java).

Comment: I know this is incorrect as you can resize an image clientside before upload here:

http://www.adylevy.com/index.php/2009/06/07/client-side-image-resize-flash-cs4-filereferencedata/

Comment: The only way I could upload the bytes to the server was to put them in the 'data' part and access them in php using $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']. Surely there must be a better way to do this and be able to upload an actual file?

Comment: This site seems to have some answers: http://labs.findsubstance.com/2008/04/03/as3-upload-encode-images/

Comment: You know, it's the Upload Post Helper class! I already have it but didn't use it for some reason :/ thanks!

Comment: Posting image data using URLRequest doesn't work in IE. Any idea what i need to do to make it work there?

Comment: It's probably better if you start a question for this, with ample details ;)